# Jetpack Compose AbstractComposeView displays as black window

Tags: kotlin, popup, android-jetpack-compose

When I create the abstract view on my android studio and open it on the emulator the pop-up window appears black, the 2 buttons are visible and I can select a text field but the rest of the window is black.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LphmR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSLjg.png)

Here is the code used to create the view:

```
class Swim_Set_Adder(
    composeView: View,
    private val Workout_Point: Workout
) : AbstractComposeView(composeView.context) {

    private val windowManager =
        composeView.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)
                as WindowManager

    private var params: WindowManager.LayoutParams =
        WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
            type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL
            token = composeView.applicationWindowToken
            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            format = PixelFormat.OPAQUE
        }

    private var viewShowing = false


    init {
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(composeView))
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(this, ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.get(composeView))
        setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(composeView.findViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner())
    }

    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Show()
    }

    fun show() {
        if (viewShowing) dismiss()
        windowManager.addView(this, params)
        viewShowing = true
    }

    fun dismiss() {
        if (!viewShowing) return
        disposeComposition()
        windowManager.removeViewImmediate(this)
        viewShowing = false
    }

    fun dispose() {
        dismiss()
        setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(null)
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, null)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(this, null)
    }

}
```

I am trying to get the window to display normally and see all the text boxes.